# What's the difference between a rhombus lattice and a hexagonal lattice in photonics?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene, photonics

I am learning **photonic crystal slabs**. I try to figure out what the difference between a **rhombus** lattice and a **hexagonal** lattice in photonics is?

[image]

All I know is that they have diffefent Brillouin zones, and corresponding band structures that are connected by a reciprocal lattice vector, that is, point K folded into point $\Gamma$

[image]

But I don't really understand the difference between the two when it comes to measuring the reflectance spectrum experimentally. I mean, no matter which lattice I use, the structure that light travels through in the experiment is the same, so how does that make a difference? And how do they result in different band structures?

If all this is true, then for a photonic crystal slab consisted of hexagonal lattices, the folding of point K to point $\Gamma$ means that I can experimentally measure the band structures, which is outside the light cone for rhombus lattice, through reflectance spectra. Such as the Dirac point.

Figures quoted from:
S. Barik et al., New J. Phys. 18, 113013 (2016).